# App doesn't launch from Facebook App Link Deep LInk on first click

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, deep-linking

I have a deep link to my app through through I webpage that I create and post to Facebook open graph using the Facebook SDK.  However, the first person to click the post is directed to the browser instead of my app.  After the first person opens the post, other users are correctly directed to the app.

Webpage HTML is this:

```
    <html> <head> 
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="myapp://0B6JA7WLVQukweEJ4OWFQbjJqWkU" > 
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.blah.myapp" > 
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="App Name" > 
    <meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="true" > 
    <meta property="og:title" content="Post Title" > 
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" > 
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://36197da29a77a6423e7262ff078abc3e5002454b.googledrive.com/host/0B6JA7WLVQukwZGdsUXRaV190cDg"> 
    </head> 
    <body> Test Post
    </body> 
    </html>
```

When I check it with the Open Graph Object Debugger there are no errors and the App Link - Android data seems correct, no typos or errors that I can see, and it shows the url as `myapp://...`.  When I click the post as the first user, I see the following in debug output: `android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://36197da29a7...` when I should be seeing `android.intent.action.VIEW dat=myapp://...`

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this to your launcher activityto be able to handle deeplink in your app..

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "https://36197da29a77a6423e7262ff078abc3e5002454b.googledrive.com -->
            <!-- It will also work for app indexing: android-app://36197da29a77a6423e7262ff078abc3e5002454b.googledrive.com -->
            <data
                android:host="36197da29a77a6423e7262ff078abc3e5002454b.googledrive.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is that facebook shouldn't be initiating and intent with the scheme `https` at all.  It should be using the `android:url` to generate an intent with `myapp`.  The app is correctly launched from another device/fb account, just not the one that initiates the post.